# Imprecise Assigned value

Tags: fortran90

In a simple program I want to build a matrix by defining a function. The problem is that a variable declared and initialized in the program has the exact assinged value of zero (`zero_test`)and some components of the matrix(`D(4,1), D(1,4)` etc.) which are assigned to `0.`, are not exactly zero. The latter have a value of order `E-308` or `E-291`etc. I wonder why is there a difference.

Due to some articles I read, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532502/why-does-a-c-floating-point-type-modify-the-actual-input-of-125-1-to-125-099998), the other components(`D(1,1), D(1,2)` etc.) are imprecise because of the transformation to the binary format.

System info: IA-32, Intel Visual Fortran 11.1.048 integrated with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008

The code:

```
program test

implicit none

real(8),parameter :: LAMBDA=75.e9,MU=50.e9
integer,parameter :: ndi=3,ntens=4
real(8) :: D(ntens,ntens),zero_test=0.


D = clcElasticStiffnessMatrix(LAMBDA,MU,ndi,ntens)

contains

        function clcElasticStiffnessMatrix(LAMBDA,MU,ndi,ntens)

        implicit none

        integer :: ndi,ntens,i,j
        real(8) :: clcElasticStiffnessMatrix(ntens,ntens),LAMBDA,MU


        do i=1,ndi    
        do j=i,ndi
            if(i .eq. j) then
                clcElasticStiffnessMatrix(i,j) = 2.*MU + LAMBDA
            else 
                clcElasticStiffnessMatrix(i,j) = LAMBDA
                clcElasticStiffnessMatrix(j,i) = clcElasticStiffnessMatrix(i,j)
            end if
        end do
        end do

        do i=ndi+1,ntens
        do j=i,ntens
            if(i .eq. j) then
                clcElasticStiffnessMatrix(i,j) = MU
            else 
                clcElasticStiffnessMatrix(i,j) = 0.
                clcElasticStiffnessMatrix(j,i) = clcElasticStiffnessMatrix(i,j)
            end if

        end do
        end do      

        end function

end program
```

Matrix `D` in break mode:

```
 D:
   174999994368.000        74999996416.0000        74999996416.0000       2.641443384627243E-308
   74999996416.0000        174999994368.000        74999996416.0000       2.640433316727162E-308
   74999996416.0000        74999996416.0000        174999994368.000      -1.051992669438322E-291
  2.640110775815455E-308  0.000000000000000E+000  6.151018477594351E-318   49999998976.0000
```

Comment: Is there any specific question you need an answer about that behavior?

Comment: Yes I want to know why the assigned variables in the matrix have a different value from zero.

Comment: You should not look for exact equality in floatting point calculations. It is strongly discouraged. Modern compilers will warn you of such comparison, instead, you should use the epsilon function.

Comment: if i understand the question its not about calculations. When a value is *assigned* to 0. it should in fact pass a `.eq.0.` test.  See what you get if you set lambda an mu to zero as well.

Comment: the error in this case is in your loop construct. you are not assigning *anything* to those matrix components that are showing up with the `E-308` junk.  My advice here initialise the entire matrix to zero, then assign the nonzero components in the loop.

Comment: You are right. Something was wrong with my loop index range. It should be `j=1,i`.  Thanks.

Comment: Is there any debugging option (flag) that could throw an error when a variable, which is not assigned to a value, is used in a statement?

Comment: You can use ` -finit-real=nan` in gfortran or the valgrind debugger.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are assigning real(4) values to real(8) variables when you write

```
LAMBDA=75.e9,MU=50.e9
```

or

```
clcElasticStiffnessMatrix(i,j) = 0.
```

Try with d instead e and specify always:

```
LAMBDA=75.d9,MU=50.d9
clcElasticStiffnessMatrix(i,j) = 0.d0
```

Comment: please see the comments under the question. The problem was in my loop's construct.